# How to get all customers ever paid/complete an order

Tags: sales-order, order-status

I am working on a custom Magento Extension.

Here is how i take all customers in a customer group:

```
                $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                                    ->getCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');


                foreach($customers as $customer)
                {

                    $email=$customer->getEmail();
                    $CustomerPhone = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
                    $CustomerName = $customer->getName();
                    $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
                 }
```

This how i get information about the users in a specific customer group.

My question is how i can get all the users ever paid or complete(for example) an order ?

Is it even possible, and if so how ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean all the users who have placed an order.?

Comment: No i mean all users who have orders with status completed.

Answer (score 3):

To find all the users who have status completed, you can load the `sales/order` collection like this :

```
$ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                 ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');
foreach($ordercollection as $_order)
{
    $customerId[]    = $_order->getCustomerId();
    $customerEmail[] = $_order->getCustomerEmail();
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($customerId); //id of all customers whose order status=complete
echo "<pre>";print_r($customerEmail); //email of all customers whose order status=complete
```